# Install of nix via nix-installers breaks system on Fedora 37

Tags: fedora, software-installation, nix

I tried to install the Nix package manager on my Fedora 37 machine. Having read about some issues with installing Nix with the install script on Fedora and other OS, using Selinux, I chose install via "nix-installers" rpm-package.

When I start a new shell and try nix everything works properly. However, when I reboot the computer, instead of landing in the Gnome Shell, I end-up with a flickering black screen and nothing works anymore. Trying to switch virtual shell with `Alt + F2` shows me login for 1 second before, again, switching to a black flickering screen.

Was anyone able to install nix on Fedora 37 or could give me advise on what might cause the problem?

I think it is not connected to the issue but during install, I get warnings about created uids throughout the install process not being in the scope of `SYS_UID_MAX 999` (see log below). The users are, nevertheless, created and exist on my OS after install.

I saw, that the warnings themselves seem to be known issue (https://github.com/nix-community/nix-installers/issues/16).

Log during install:

```bash
sudo dnf localinstall ./nix-multi-user-2.9.1.rpm 
[sudo] Passwort für firestarter: 
Letzte Prüfung auf abgelaufene Metadaten: vor 0:43:30 am Mo 06 Feb 2023 19:33:24 CET.
Abhängigkeiten sind aufgelöst.
=====================================================================================================================================
 Paket                              Architektur                Version                        Paketquelle                      Größe
=====================================================================================================================================
Installieren:
 nix-multi-user                     x86_64                     2.9.1-1                        @commandline                      40 M

Transaktionszusammenfassung
=====================================================================================================================================
Installieren  1 Paket

Gesamtgröße: 40 M
Installationsgröße: 40 M
Ist dies in Ordnung? [j/N]: j
Pakete werden heruntergeladen:
Transaktionsüberprüfung wird ausgeführt
Transaktionsüberprüfung war erfolgreich.
Transaktion wird getestet
Transaktionstest war erfolgreich.
Transaktion wird ausgeführt
  Vorbereitung läuft    :                                                                                                        1/1 
  Installieren          : nix-multi-user-2.9.1-1.x86_64                                                                          1/1 
  Ausgeführtes Scriptlet: nix-multi-user-2.9.1-1.x86_64                                                                          1/1 
useradd warning: nixbld1's uid 30001 is greater than SYS_UID_MAX 999
useradd warning: nixbld2's uid 30002 is greater than SYS_UID_MAX 999
useradd warning: nixbld3's uid 30003 is greater than SYS_UID_MAX 999
useradd warning: nixbld4's uid 30004 is greater than SYS_UID_MAX 999
useradd warning: nixbld5's uid 30005 is greater than SYS_UID_MAX 999
useradd warning: nixbld6's uid 30006 is greater than SYS_UID_MAX 999
useradd warning: nixbld7's uid 30007 is greater than SYS_UID_MAX 999
useradd warning: nixbld8's uid 30008 is greater than SYS_UID_MAX 999
useradd warning: nixbld9's uid 30009 is greater than SYS_UID_MAX 999
useradd warning: nixbld10's uid 30010 is greater than SYS_UID_MAX 999
useradd warning: nixbld11's uid 30011 is greater than SYS_UID_MAX 999
useradd warning: nixbld12's uid 30012 is greater than SYS_UID_MAX 999
useradd warning: nixbld13's uid 30013 is greater than SYS_UID_MAX 999
useradd warning: nixbld14's uid 30014 is greater than SYS_UID_MAX 999
useradd warning: nixbld15's uid 30015 is greater than SYS_UID_MAX 999
useradd warning: nixbld16's uid 30016 is greater than SYS_UID_MAX 999
useradd warning: nixbld17's uid 30017 is greater than SYS_UID_MAX 999
useradd warning: nixbld18's uid 30018 is greater than SYS_UID_MAX 999
useradd warning: nixbld19's uid 30019 is greater than SYS_UID_MAX 999
useradd warning: nixbld20's uid 30020 is greater than SYS_UID_MAX 999
useradd warning: nixbld21's uid 30021 is greater than SYS_UID_MAX 999
useradd warning: nixbld22's uid 30022 is greater than SYS_UID_MAX 999
useradd warning: nixbld23's uid 30023 is greater than SYS_UID_MAX 999
useradd warning: nixbld24's uid 30024 is greater than SYS_UID_MAX 999
useradd warning: nixbld25's uid 30025 is greater than SYS_UID_MAX 999
useradd warning: nixbld26's uid 30026 is greater than SYS_UID_MAX 999
useradd warning: nixbld27's uid 30027 is greater than SYS_UID_MAX 999
useradd warning: nixbld28's uid 30028 is greater than SYS_UID_MAX 999
useradd warning: nixbld29's uid 30029 is greater than SYS_UID_MAX 999
useradd warning: nixbld30's uid 30030 is greater than SYS_UID_MAX 999
useradd warning: nixbld31's uid 30031 is greater than SYS_UID_MAX 999
useradd warning: nixbld32's uid 30032 is greater than SYS_UID_MAX 999
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/nix-daemon.service → /usr/lib/systemd/system/nix-daemon.service.

  Überprüfung läuft     : nix-multi-user-2.9.1-1.x86_64                                                                          1/1 

Installiert:
  nix-multi-user-2.9.1-1.x86_64                                                                                                      

Fertig!
```